# How to use ajax in Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I am trying following.

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('register_script_name', "
    $('.text-warning').click(function(){

        var id = $(this).attr('value');
        alert(id);
        $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'/jobMaster/test'/id/'+id,
                    success:function(ajaxresponse){ 

                               },
                    error:function(ajaxresponse){ 

                                      });
                              },

                                    });
       return false;
    });
");
```

But my ajax url " url:'/jobMaster/test'/id/'+id," doesn't called.If i don't use ajax it works. what is wrong?

Comment: u can use EOD ... to make it more simpler...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Your code is worng, try like this -

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('register_script_name', "
    $('.text-warning').click(function(){

        var id = $this.value;
        alert(id);
        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'".Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('jobMaster/test')."',
                data:'id='+id
                success:function(response){ 

                        },
               error:function(er){ 

                   }
           });
       return false;
    });
");
```

Answer (score 0):

> url:'/jobMaster/test'/id/'+id,

here you've messed with `'`

probably you need to do it this way:

```
url:'/jobMaster/test/id/'+id,
```

Also, check the bracket levels.